# Programmatically copy indexes from one table to another in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Basically the exact same question as in this question: [How to copy indexes from one table to another in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652148/how-to-copy-indexes-from-one-table-to-another-in-sqlserver), BUT, how do I do it programmatically in T-SQL, given a source table name and destination table name?

I.e. without knowing what table up front.

I can copy the basic structure

```
SELECT TOP (0) * INTO [BackupTable] FROM [OriginalTable]
```

But that doesn't copy indexes, constraints, triggers etc

I ideally would like a stored proc that looks something like:

```
spCloneTableStructure @ExistingTableName, @NewTableName
```

That copies the columns, primary keys and indexes

Anything like that exist? (note that I'm on SQL Server 2008 R2)

Comment: Is using TSQL a fixed requirement and if so, why? The preferred solution for scripting objects is to use Smo from PowerShell, C# or another .NET language.

Comment: SQL 2008 r2 allows powershell from within SSMS

Comment: Yea, I know, but I have a requirement to do it in TSQL as it will be part of a larger batch (which is TSQL)

Comment: @Gareth - **Then you should probably rethink your process design.**  This is not something that is a good candidate to do in a script.  It will involve creating DDL scripts with dynamic SQL, **which is very perilous.**

Comment: @Gareth, I agree with JNK's comment that you should reconsider your overall process here. But if you absolutely must drive things from pure TSQL, you could use Smo inside a CLR procedure and just call the procedure from TSQL.

Comment: @Gareth Or you could do a Powershell script and call it using `Xp_cmdshell` from within the script.

Comment: hmmm, thanks for the suggestions, but this is for a locked down corporate - so TSQL is the only option unfortunately... I've started looking at an approach based on JNK's answer below. It shouldn't be too hard - I'm not concerned with triggers, constraints or foreign keys...

Comment: @Gareth - it will be easy if you don't have any complicated indexes.  If you have filters, or included fields, or non-standard padding, or PK constraints, or UNIQUE constraints, then it'll be very complicated to do correctly.

Comment: @JNK, yes, completely agreed. Thankfully, the tables concerned have simple indexes etc, so I don't see a problem.

Comment: @Gareth - OK, good news.  If they are all just like single-field non-included indexes then I could write a single query for it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is what I came up with. It works for me and copies all the stuff I care about.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCloneTableStructure]
    @SourceSchema nvarchar(255),
    @SourceTable nvarchar(255),
    @DestinationSchema nvarchar(255),
    @DestinationTable nvarchar(255),
    @RecreateIfExists bit = 0
AS
BEGIN
    /*
        Clones an existing table to another table (without data)
        Optionally drops and re-creates target table
        Copies:
            * Structure
            * Primary key
            * Indexes (including ASC/DESC, included columns, filters)
            * Constraints (and unique constraints)

        DOES NOT copy:
            * Triggers
            * File groups
            * Probably a lot of other things

        Note: Assumes that you name (unique) constraints with the table name in it (in order to not duplicate constraint names)
    */
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    --drop the table
    if EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @DestinationSchema AND TABLE_NAME = @DestinationTable)
    BEGIN
        if @RecreateIfExists = 1
        BEGIN
            exec('DROP TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + ']')
        END
        ELSE
            RETURN
    END

    --create the table
    exec('SELECT TOP (0) * INTO [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] FROM [' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']')

    DECLARE @PKSchema nvarchar(255), @PKName nvarchar(255)
    SELECT TOP 1 @PKSchema = CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, @PKName = CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @SourceSchema AND TABLE_NAME = @SourceTable AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'

    --create primary key
    IF NOT @PKSchema IS NULL AND NOT @PKName IS NULL
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @PKColumns nvarchar(MAX)
        SET @PKColumns = ''

        SELECT @PKColumns = @PKColumns + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '],'
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
            where TABLE_NAME = @SourceTable and TABLE_SCHEMA = @SourceSchema AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = @PKSchema AND CONSTRAINT_NAME= @PKName
            ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

        SET @PKColumns = LEFT(@PKColumns, LEN(@PKColumns) - 1)

        exec('ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_' + @DestinationTable + '] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (' + @PKColumns + ')');
    END

    --create other indexes
    DECLARE @IndexId int, @IndexName nvarchar(255), @IsUnique bit, @IsUniqueConstraint bit, @FilterDefinition nvarchar(max)

    DECLARE indexcursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT index_id, name, is_unique, is_unique_constraint, filter_definition FROM sys.indexes WHERE type = 2 and object_id = object_id('[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']')
    OPEN indexcursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM indexcursor INTO @IndexId, @IndexName, @IsUnique, @IsUniqueConstraint, @FilterDefinition;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN
            DECLARE @Unique nvarchar(255)
            SET @Unique = CASE WHEN @IsUnique = 1 THEN ' UNIQUE ' ELSE '' END

            DECLARE @KeyColumns nvarchar(max), @IncludedColumns nvarchar(max)
            SET @KeyColumns = ''
            SET @IncludedColumns = ''

            select @KeyColumns = @KeyColumns + '[' + c.name + '] ' + CASE WHEN is_descending_key = 1 THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END + ',' from sys.index_columns ic
            inner join sys.columns c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id and c.column_id = ic.column_id
            where index_id = @IndexId and ic.object_id = object_id('[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']') and key_ordinal > 0
            order by index_column_id

            select @IncludedColumns = @IncludedColumns + '[' + c.name + '],' from sys.index_columns ic
            inner join sys.columns c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id and c.column_id = ic.column_id
            where index_id = @IndexId and ic.object_id = object_id('[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']') and key_ordinal = 0
            order by index_column_id

            IF LEN(@KeyColumns) > 0
                SET @KeyColumns = LEFT(@KeyColumns, LEN(@KeyColumns) - 1)

            IF LEN(@IncludedColumns) > 0
            BEGIN
                SET @IncludedColumns = ' INCLUDE (' + LEFT(@IncludedColumns, LEN(@IncludedColumns) - 1) + ')'
            END

            IF @FilterDefinition IS NULL
                SET @FilterDefinition = ''
            ELSE
                SET @FilterDefinition = 'WHERE ' + @FilterDefinition + ' '

            if @IsUniqueConstraint = 0
                exec('CREATE ' + @Unique + ' NONCLUSTERED INDEX [' + @IndexName + '] ON [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] (' + @KeyColumns + ')' + @IncludedColumns + @FilterDefinition)
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @IndexName = REPLACE(@IndexName, @SourceTable, @DestinationTable)
                    exec('ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] ADD  CONSTRAINT [' + @IndexName + '] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (' + @KeyColumns + ')');
                END

            FETCH NEXT FROM indexcursor INTO @IndexId, @IndexName, @IsUnique, @IsUniqueConstraint, @FilterDefinition;
       END;
    CLOSE indexcursor;
    DEALLOCATE indexcursor;

    --create constraints
    DECLARE @ConstraintName nvarchar(max), @CheckClause nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE constraintcursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT REPLACE(c.CONSTRAINT_NAME, @SourceTable, @DestinationTable), CHECK_CLAUSE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE t
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS c ON c.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = TABLE_SCHEMA AND c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
         WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @SourceSchema AND TABLE_NAME = @SourceTable
    OPEN constraintcursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM constraintcursor INTO @ConstraintName, @CheckClause;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN
            exec('ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [' + @ConstraintName + '] CHECK ' + @CheckClause)
            exec('ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + @ConstraintName + ']')
            FETCH NEXT FROM constraintcursor INTO @ConstraintName, @CheckClause;
       END;
    CLOSE constraintcursor;
    DEALLOCATE constraintcursor;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: you deserve much more then just +1 more like +100 but this is all i can give so thank you.

Comment: I agree with Liran! Thank you so much for this.

Comment: Yes, this is really a great stuff!
Perfectly works with "switch" option, when moving data from one table to another.

Comment: Thanks nice works, be carefull  with cluster index or primary key not cluster; clusterd index are changed to not cluster

Comment: Constraints copy  Does not seem to work  as I got below error:

Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
There is already an object named 'CK__XXX' in the database.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Any idea if i need to make some changes in the procedure

Answer (score 4):

I have made some alterations to Gareth's work, which BTW works and I think is great. I wanted to include cloning the Triggers and copy the tables content as well. In essence "copy" as much of the table as best I can in one shot. I have included the whole piece of code. Remember this is not completely original, and I do not claim credit for any of Gareth's hard work. I hope this is useful for anyone interested.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCloneTableStructure]
    @SourceSchema nvarchar(255)
    , @SourceTable nvarchar(255)
    , @DestinationSchema nvarchar(255)
    , @DestinationTable nvarchar(255)
    , @RecreateIfExists bit = 0
AS
BEGIN
/*    
Clones an existing table to another table (without data)
Optionally drops and re-creates target table
Copies:
    * Structure
    * Primary key
    * Indexes (including ASC/DESC, included columns, filters)
    * Constraints (and unique constraints)

DOES NOT copy:
    * Triggers (It seems to do this now)
    * File groups
    * Probably a lot of other things

Note: Assumes that you name (unique) constraints with the table name in it (in order to not duplicate constraint names)
*/

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    --drop the table
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @DestinationSchema AND TABLE_NAME = @DestinationTable)
        BEGIN
            IF @RecreateIfExists = 1
                BEGIN
                    EXEC('DROP TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + ']')
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    RETURN
                END
        END

    --create the table
    EXEC('SELECT TOP (0) * INTO [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] FROM [' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']')

    DECLARE @PKSchema nvarchar(255), @PKName nvarchar(255)
    SELECT TOP 1 @PKSchema = CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, @PKName = CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @SourceSchema 
        AND TABLE_NAME = @SourceTable 
        AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @SourceColumns int
DECLARE @DestinationColumns int
DECLARE @MyColumn int

SELECT @SourceColumns = count(*) 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @SourceTable
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @SourceSchema

SELECT @DestinationColumns = count(*) 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @DestinationTable
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @DestinationSchema


IF @SourceColumns = @DestinationColumns
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @FullSourceTable varchar(128)
        DECLARE @FullDestinationTable varchar(128)

        SET @FullSourceTable = @SourceSchema+'.'+@SourceTable
        SET @FullDestinationTable = @DestinationSchema+'.'+@DestinationTable

        DECLARE @MySQL varchar(MAX)
        DECLARE @MyValues varchar(MAX)

        SET @MyColumn = 2

        SET @MySQL = 'INSERT INTO '+@FullDestinationTable+' ('

        SET @MyValues = COL_NAME(OBJECT_ID(@FullSourceTable), 1) + ', '

        WHILE @MyColumn <= @DestinationColumns --Change this back 
            BEGIN
                SET @MyValues = @MyValues+ COL_NAME(OBJECT_ID(@FullSourceTable), @MyColumn) + ', '
                SET @MyColumn = @MyColumn + 1
            END

        SELECT @MyValues = SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(@MyValues)),1,DATALENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(@MyValues)))-1)
        SET @MySQL = @MySQL+@MyValues+') '
        SET @MySQL = @MySQL+' SELECT '+@MyValues+' FROM '+@FullSourceTable

        --SELECT @MySQL
        EXEC(@MySQL)
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Number of Source and Destination Columns do not match. Cannot continue with copying content.',16,1)
    END

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --create primary key
    IF NOT @PKSchema IS NULL 
        AND NOT @PKName IS NULL
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @PKColumns nvarchar(MAX)
            SET @PKColumns = ''

            SELECT @PKColumns = @PKColumns + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '],'
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = @SourceTable 
                AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @SourceSchema 
                AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = @PKSchema 
                AND CONSTRAINT_NAME= @PKName
                ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

            SET @PKColumns = LEFT(@PKColumns, LEN(@PKColumns) - 1)

            EXEC('ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_' + @DestinationTable + '] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (' + @PKColumns + ')');
        END

    --create other indexes
    DECLARE @IndexId int, @IndexName nvarchar(255), @IsUnique bit, @IsUniqueConstraint bit, @FilterDefinition nvarchar(max)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Cursor Start
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    DECLARE indexcursor CURSOR FOR

        SELECT index_id, name, is_unique, is_unique_constraint, filter_definition 
            FROM sys.indexes 
                WHERE type = 2 
                AND object_id = object_id('[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']')

    OPEN indexcursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM indexcursor INTO @IndexId, @IndexName, @IsUnique, @IsUniqueConstraint, @FilterDefinition;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN
            DECLARE @Unique nvarchar(255)
            DECLARE @KeyColumns nvarchar(max), @IncludedColumns nvarchar(max)


            SET @Unique = CASE WHEN @IsUnique = 1 THEN ' UNIQUE ' ELSE '' END
            SET @KeyColumns = ''
            SET @IncludedColumns = ''

            SELECT @KeyColumns = @KeyColumns + '[' + c.name + '] ' + CASE WHEN is_descending_key = 1 THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END + ',' 
                FROM sys.index_columns ic
                    INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
                        ON c.object_id = ic.object_id 
                        AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                WHERE index_id = @IndexId 
                AND ic.object_id = object_id('[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']') 
                AND key_ordinal > 0
                ORDER BY index_column_id

            SELECT @IncludedColumns = @IncludedColumns + '[' + c.name + '],' 
                FROM sys.index_columns ic
                    INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
                        ON c.object_id = ic.object_id 
                        AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                WHERE index_id = @IndexId 
                AND ic.object_id = object_id('[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']') 
                AND key_ordinal = 0
                ORDER BY index_column_id

            IF LEN(@KeyColumns) > 0
                BEGIN
                    SET @KeyColumns = LEFT(@KeyColumns, LEN(@KeyColumns) - 1)
                END

            IF LEN(@IncludedColumns) > 0
                BEGIN
                    SET @IncludedColumns = ' INCLUDE (' + LEFT(@IncludedColumns, LEN(@IncludedColumns) - 1) + ')'
                END

            IF @FilterDefinition IS NULL
                BEGIN
                    SET @FilterDefinition = ''
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @FilterDefinition = 'WHERE ' + @FilterDefinition + ' '
                END

            IF @IsUniqueConstraint = 0
                BEGIN
                    EXEC('CREATE ' + @Unique + ' NONCLUSTERED INDEX [' + @IndexName + '] ON [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] (' + @KeyColumns + ')' + @IncludedColumns + @FilterDefinition)
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @IndexName = REPLACE(@IndexName, @SourceTable, @DestinationTable)
                    EXEC('ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] ADD  CONSTRAINT [' + @IndexName + '] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (' + @KeyColumns + ')');
                END

            FETCH NEXT FROM indexcursor INTO @IndexId, @IndexName, @IsUnique, @IsUniqueConstraint, @FilterDefinition;
       END;
    CLOSE indexcursor;
    DEALLOCATE indexcursor;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Cursor END
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --create constraints
    DECLARE @ConstraintName nvarchar(max), @CheckClause nvarchar(max)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Cursor START
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DECLARE constraintcursor CURSOR FOR

        SELECT REPLACE(c.CONSTRAINT_NAME, @SourceTable, @DestinationTable), CHECK_CLAUSE 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE t
                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS c 
                    ON c.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = TABLE_SCHEMA 
                    AND c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @SourceSchema 
            AND TABLE_NAME = @SourceTable

    OPEN constraintcursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM constraintcursor INTO @ConstraintName, @CheckClause;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN
            EXEC('ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [' + @ConstraintName + '] CHECK ' + @CheckClause)
            EXEC('ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + @ConstraintName + ']')
            FETCH NEXT FROM constraintcursor INTO @ConstraintName, @CheckClause;
       END;
    CLOSE constraintcursor;
    DEALLOCATE constraintcursor;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Cursor END
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Build Triggers on new table START
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @TriggerType varchar(32)
DECLARE @CHeader varchar(255)

DECLARE @trigger_name varchar(128)
DECLARE @table_schema varchar(128)
DECLARE @table_name varchar(128)
DECLARE @isupdate tinyint
DECLARE @isdelete tinyint
DECLARE @isinsert tinyint
DECLARE @isafter tinyint
DECLARE @isinsteadof tinyint
DECLARE @disabled tinyint
DECLARE @TriggerCode varchar(MAX)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR

SELECT so.name 
    ,( SELECT TOP 1 SCHEMA_NAME(T1.schema_id)
                        FROM sys.tables AS T1
                        WHERE  T1.name = OBJECT_NAME(parent_obj))
    ,OBJECT_NAME(parent_obj)
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY(so.id, 'ExecIsUpdateTrigger')
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY(so.id, 'ExecIsDeleteTrigger')
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY(so.id, 'ExecIsInsertTrigger')
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY(so.id, 'ExecIsAfterTrigger')
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY(so.id, 'ExecIsInsteadOfTrigger')
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY(so.id, 'ExecIsTriggerDisabled')
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(c.[text]))
    FROM sys.sysobjects AS so
        INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON so.id = o.object_id
        INNER JOIN  sys.syscomments AS c ON o.object_id = c.id
    WHERE so.type = 'TR'
    AND OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) = @SourceTable

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @trigger_name, @table_schema, @table_name, @isupdate, @isdelete, @isinsert, @isafter, @isinsteadof, @disabled, @TriggerCode

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       --SELECT  @trigger_name, @table_schema, @table_name, @isupdate, @isdelete, @isinsert, @isafter, @isinsteadof, @disabled, @TriggerCode

        SET @TriggerCode = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@TriggerCode, CHAR(13)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(13), CHAR(13))))
        SET @TriggerCode = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@TriggerCode, CHAR(13)+CHAR(13), CHAR(13))))
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Which one is first?
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        DECLARE @MyStart tinyint
        DECLARE @MyForStart tinyint
        DECLARE @MyAfterStart tinyint
        DECLARE @MyInsteadStart tinyint

        SELECT @MyForStart = CHARINDEX('for',@TriggerCode)
        SELECT @TriggerType = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@TriggerCode,CHARINDEX('for',@TriggerCode)-1, 4 )))

        SELECT @MyAfterStart = CHARINDEX('after',@TriggerCode)
        SELECT @TriggerType = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@TriggerCode,CHARINDEX('after',@TriggerCode)-1, 6 )))

        SELECT @MyInsteadStart = CHARINDEX('instead',@TriggerCode)
        SELECT @TriggerType = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@TriggerCode,CHARINDEX('Instead',@TriggerCode)-1, 8 )))

        IF @MyAfterStart <> 0
            AND @MyAfterStart < @MyForStart
            BEGIN
                SET @MyStart = @MyAfterStart
                SELECT @TriggerType = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@TriggerCode,@MyStart-1, 6 )))
            END
        ELSE IF @MyInsteadStart <> 0
            AND @MyInsteadStart < @MyForStart 
            BEGIN
                SET @MyStart = @MyInsteadStart
                SELECT @TriggerType = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@TriggerCode,@MyStart-1, 8 )))
            END
        ELSE IF @MyForStart <> 0
            AND @MyForStart < @MyAfterStart
            AND @MyForStart < @MyInsteadStart
            BEGIN
                SET @MyStart = @MyForStart
                SELECT @TriggerType = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@TriggerCode,@MyStart-1, 4 )))
            END
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Build the correct header and append it to the create trigger code then run it
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        IF @TriggerType LIKE '%FOR%'
            BEGIN
                SET @CHeader = 'CREATE TRIGGER ['+@DestinationSchema+'].['+@trigger_name+'] ON ['+@DestinationSchema+'].['+@DestinationTable+']'
                --print @CHeader+char(13)+SUBSTRING(@TriggerCode,CHARINDEX('FOR',@TriggerCode)-1,DATALENGTH(@TriggerCode))
                SET @TriggerCode = @CHeader+char(13)+SUBSTRING(@TriggerCode,CHARINDEX('for',@TriggerCode)-1,DATALENGTH(@TriggerCode))
                EXEC(@TriggerCode)
            END
        ELSE IF @TriggerType LIKE '%AFTER%'
            BEGIN
                SET @CHeader = 'CREATE TRIGGER ['+@DestinationSchema+'].['+@trigger_name+'] ON ['+@DestinationSchema+'].['+@DestinationTable+']'
                --print @CHeader+char(13)+SUBSTRING(@TriggerCode,CHARINDEX('AFTER',@TriggerCode)-1,DATALENGTH(@TriggerCode))
                SET @TriggerCode = @CHeader+char(13)+SUBSTRING(@TriggerCode,CHARINDEX('after',@TriggerCode)-1,DATALENGTH(@TriggerCode))
                EXEC(@TriggerCode)
            END
        ELSE IF @TriggerType LIKE '%INSTEAD%'
            BEGIN
                SET @CHeader = 'CREATE TRIGGER ['+@DestinationSchema+'].['+@trigger_name+'] ON ['+@DestinationSchema+'].['+@DestinationTable+']'
                --print @CHeader+char(13)+SUBSTRING(@TriggerCode,CHARINDEX('INSTEAD',@TriggerCode)-1,DATALENGTH(@TriggerCode))
                SET @TriggerCode = @CHeader+char(13)+SUBSTRING(@TriggerCode,CHARINDEX('instead',@TriggerCode)-1,DATALENGTH(@TriggerCode))
                EXEC(@TriggerCode)
            END

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @trigger_name, @table_schema, @table_name, @isupdate, @isdelete, @isinsert, @isafter, @isinsteadof, @disabled, @TriggerCode
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor


COMMIT TRANSACTION

END
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Gareth. That works. I have altered to work across databases:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCloneDatabaseTableStructurev3] 
    @SourceDatabase nvarchar(max),
    @SourceSchema nvarchar(max),
    @SourceTable nvarchar(max),
    @DestinationDatabase nvarchar(max),
    @DestinationSchema nvarchar(max),
    @DestinationTable nvarchar(max),
    @RecreateIfExists bit = 0
AS
BEGIN
    /*
        Clones an existing table to another table (without data)
        Optionally drops and re-creates target table
        Copies:
            * Structure
            * Primary key
            * Indexes (including ASC/DESC, included columns, filters)
            * Constraints (and unique constraints)

        DOES NOT copy:
            * Triggers
            * File groups
            * Probably a lot of other things

        Note: Assumes that you name (unique) constraints with the table name in it (in order to not duplicate constraint names)
    */
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    set @sql = '
        declare @RecreateIfExists bit = ' + convert(varchar(max),@RecreateIfExists) + '
        --drop the table
        if EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [' + @DestinationDatabase + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + @DestinationSchema + ''' AND TABLE_NAME = ''' + @DestinationTable + ''')
        BEGIN
            if @RecreateIfExists = 1
            BEGIN
                DROP TABLE [' + @DestinationDatabase + '].[' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + ']
            END
            ELSE
                RETURN
        END

        --create the table
        SELECT TOP (0) * INTO [' + @DestinationDatabase + '].[' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] FROM [' + @SourceDatabase + '].[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']

        DECLARE @PKSchema nvarchar(255), @PKName nvarchar(255)
        SELECT TOP 1 @PKSchema = CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, @PKName = CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM [' + @SourceDatabase + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + @SourceSchema + ''' AND TABLE_NAME = ''' + @SourceTable + ''' AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = ''PRIMARY KEY''

        --create primary key
        IF NOT @PKSchema IS NULL AND NOT @PKName IS NULL
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @PKColumns nvarchar(MAX)
            SET @PKColumns = ''''

            SELECT @PKColumns = @PKColumns + ''['' + COLUMN_NAME + ''],''
                FROM [' + @SourceDatabase + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
                where TABLE_NAME = ''' + @SourceTable + ''' and TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + @SourceSchema + ''' AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = @PKSchema AND CONSTRAINT_NAME= @PKName
                ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

            SET @PKColumns = LEFT(@PKColumns, LEN(@PKColumns) - 1)

            exec(''ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationDatabase + '].[' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_' + @DestinationTable + '] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ('' + @PKColumns + '')'')
        END

        --create other indexes
        DECLARE @IndexId int, @IndexName nvarchar(255), @IsUnique bit, @IsUniqueConstraint bit, @FilterDefinition nvarchar(max)

        DECLARE indexcursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT index_id, name, is_unique, is_unique_constraint, filter_definition FROM sys.indexes WHERE type = 2 and object_id = object_id(''[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']'')
        OPEN indexcursor;
        FETCH NEXT FROM indexcursor INTO @IndexId, @IndexName, @IsUnique, @IsUniqueConstraint, @FilterDefinition;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
           BEGIN
                DECLARE @Unique nvarchar(255)
                SET @Unique = CASE WHEN @IsUnique = 1 THEN '' UNIQUE '' ELSE '''' END

                DECLARE @KeyColumns nvarchar(max), @IncludedColumns nvarchar(max)
                SET @KeyColumns = ''''
                SET @IncludedColumns = ''''

                select @KeyColumns = @KeyColumns + ''['' + c.name + ''] '' + CASE WHEN is_descending_key = 1 THEN ''DESC'' ELSE ''ASC'' END + '','' from sys.index_columns ic
                inner join sys.columns c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id and c.column_id = ic.column_id
                where index_id = @IndexId and ic.object_id = object_id(''[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']'') and key_ordinal > 0
                order by index_column_id

                select @IncludedColumns = @IncludedColumns + ''['' + c.name + ''],'' from sys.index_columns ic
                inner join sys.columns c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id and c.column_id = ic.column_id
                where index_id = @IndexId and ic.object_id = object_id(''[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']'') and key_ordinal = 0
                order by index_column_id

                IF LEN(@KeyColumns) > 0
                    SET @KeyColumns = LEFT(@KeyColumns, LEN(@KeyColumns) - 1)

                IF LEN(@IncludedColumns) > 0
                BEGIN
                    SET @IncludedColumns = '' INCLUDE ('' + LEFT(@IncludedColumns, LEN(@IncludedColumns) - 1) + '')''
                END

                IF @FilterDefinition IS NULL
                    SET @FilterDefinition = ''''
                ELSE
                    SET @FilterDefinition = ''WHERE '' + @FilterDefinition + '' ''

                if @IsUniqueConstraint = 0
                    exec(''CREATE '' + @Unique + '' NONCLUSTERED INDEX ['' + @IndexName + ''] ON [' + @DestinationDatabase + '].[' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] ('' + @KeyColumns + '')'' + @IncludedColumns + @FilterDefinition)
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SET @IndexName = REPLACE(@IndexName, ''' + @SourceTable + ''', ''' + @DestinationTable + ''')
                        exec(''ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationDatabase + '].[' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] ADD  CONSTRAINT ['' + @IndexName + ''] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ('' + @KeyColumns + '')'')
                    END

                FETCH NEXT FROM indexcursor INTO @IndexId, @IndexName, @IsUnique, @IsUniqueConstraint, @FilterDefinition;
           END;
        CLOSE indexcursor;
        DEALLOCATE indexcursor;

        --create constraints
        DECLARE @ConstraintName nvarchar(max), @CheckClause nvarchar(max)
        DECLARE constraintcursor CURSOR FOR
            SELECT REPLACE(c.CONSTRAINT_NAME, ''' + @SourceTable + ''', ''' + @DestinationTable + '''), CHECK_CLAUSE from [' + @SourceDatabase + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE t
            INNER JOIN [' + @SourceDatabase + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS c ON c.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = TABLE_SCHEMA AND c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
             WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + @SourceSchema + ''' AND TABLE_NAME = ''' + @SourceTable + '''
        OPEN constraintcursor;
        FETCH NEXT FROM constraintcursor INTO @ConstraintName, @CheckClause;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
           BEGIN
                exec(''ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationDatabase + '].[' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT ['' + @ConstraintName + ''] CHECK '' + @CheckClause)
                exec(''ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationDatabase + '].[' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] CHECK CONSTRAINT ['' + @ConstraintName + '']'')
                FETCH NEXT FROM constraintcursor INTO @ConstraintName, @CheckClause;
           END;
        CLOSE constraintcursor;
        DEALLOCATE constraintcursor;'

    exec(@sql)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Answer (score 2):

To give you an idea of what's involved (and why you should use SMO for this as mentioned in comments):

- Get list of indexes from `sys.indexes` based on the object_ID of the source table

  - This includes other info like `UNIQUE`, `PK`, `IGNORE_DUP_KEY`, `FILL_FACTOR`, `PADDED`, `DISABLED`, `ROW LOCKS`, `PAGE LOCKS` **which will all need to be coded separately in your dynamic SQL**
- Get list of all key fields (and their order, and if they are ASC or DESC) for each index from `sys.index_columns`.  **This will involve `JOIN`ing `sys.columns` for the names since they are all column `ID`s**
- Get list of included fields from `sys.index_columns`
- Get a list of filters for each index from `sys.indexes`

**Now translate all the above data into valid SQL scripts to execute on the target table.**

For efficiency you should also script out the clustered index first and run it, since it will take longer to build a cluster if there are already non-clustered indexes in place.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Gareth. Good work! I needed a TSQL script which works across databases. Basicly what F_Face did. I've adjusted F_Face modification because there is still a hard coded database name and some statements are relying on that.

Anyway, I agree to all the comments that this isn't the way a deep structure copy of a table should be done. Use SMO via PowerShell via xp_cmdshell via TSQL to do it in a propper way would be my suggestion. In that way SMO is taking care that everything is copied and that next SQL Server generation works as well with it.

This mentioned, here the code:

```
--If the SP exists, we do nothing. If we would drop it, we would loose security settings. 
--If the SP doesn't exist, create a dummy SP to be able to use ALTER PROCEDURE in both cases. 
DECLARE @spName varchar(255)
SET @spName='spCloneTableStructure'
IF object_id(@spName) IS NULL --does the SP exist?
    EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.'+@spName+' AS SELECT 1') --create dummy sp
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCloneTableStructure] 
    @SourceDatabase nvarchar(max),
    @SourceSchema nvarchar(max),
    @SourceTable nvarchar(max),
    @DestinationDatabase nvarchar(max),
    @DestinationSchema nvarchar(max),
    @DestinationTable nvarchar(max),
    @RecreateIfExists bit = 0
AS
BEGIN
    /*
    Clones an existing table to another table (without data)
    Optionally drops and re-creates target table
    Copies:
        * Structure
        * Primary key
        * Indexes (including ASC/DESC, included columns, filters)
        * Constraints (and unique constraints)

    DOES NOT copy:
        * Triggers
        * File groups
        * Probably a lot of other things

    Note: Assumes that you name (unique) constraints with the table name in it (in order to not duplicate constraint names)
*/
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION

set @sql = 
    'DECLARE @RecreateIfExists bit = ' + convert(varchar(max),@RecreateIfExists) + '
    --drop the table
    if EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [' + @DestinationDatabase + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + @DestinationSchema + ''' 
                 AND TABLE_NAME = ''' + @DestinationTable + ''')
    BEGIN
        IF @RecreateIfExists = 1
        BEGIN
            DROP TABLE [' + @DestinationDatabase + '].[' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + ']
        END
        ELSE
            RETURN
    END

    --create the table
    SELECT TOP (0) * INTO [' + @DestinationDatabase + '].[' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] 
      FROM [' + @SourceDatabase + '].[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']

    DECLARE @PKSchema nvarchar(255), @PKName nvarchar(255)
    SELECT TOP 1 @PKSchema = CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, @PKName = CONSTRAINT_NAME 
      FROM [' + @SourceDatabase + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
      WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + @SourceSchema + ''' 
      AND TABLE_NAME = ''' + @SourceTable + ''' 
      AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = ''PRIMARY KEY''

    --create primary key
    IF NOT @PKSchema IS NULL AND NOT @PKName IS NULL
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @PKColumns nvarchar(MAX)
        SET @PKColumns = ''''

        SELECT @PKColumns = @PKColumns + ''['' + COLUMN_NAME + ''],''
          FROM [' + @SourceDatabase + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
          WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @SourceTable + ''' 
          AND TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + @SourceSchema + ''' 
          AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = @PKSchema 
          AND CONSTRAINT_NAME= @PKName
          ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

        SET @PKColumns = LEFT(@PKColumns, LEN(@PKColumns) - 1)

        EXEC(''ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationDatabase + '].[' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] 
               ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_' + @DestinationTable + '] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ('' + @PKColumns + '')'')
    END

    --create other indexes
    DECLARE @IndexId int, @IndexName nvarchar(255), @IsUnique bit, @IsUniqueConstraint bit, @FilterDefinition nvarchar(max)

    DECLARE indexcursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT index_id, name, is_unique, is_unique_constraint, filter_definition 
      FROM ['+@SourceDatabase+'].sys.indexes 
      WHERE type = 2 
      AND object_id = object_id(''['+@SourceDatabase+'].[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']'')
    OPEN indexcursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM indexcursor INTO @IndexId, @IndexName, @IsUnique, @IsUniqueConstraint, @FilterDefinition;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN
            DECLARE @Unique nvarchar(255)
            SET @Unique = CASE WHEN @IsUnique = 1 THEN '' UNIQUE '' ELSE '''' END

            DECLARE @KeyColumns nvarchar(max), @IncludedColumns nvarchar(max)
            SET @KeyColumns = ''''
            SET @IncludedColumns = ''''

            SELECT @KeyColumns = @KeyColumns + ''['' + c.name + ''] '' + CASE WHEN is_descending_key = 1 THEN ''DESC'' ELSE ''ASC'' END + '','' 
              FROM ['+@SourceDatabase+'].sys.index_columns ic
              INNER JOIN ['+@SourceDatabase+'].sys.columns c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id and c.column_id = ic.column_id
              WHERE index_id = @IndexId 
              AND ic.object_id = object_id(''['+@SourceDatabase+'].[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']'') 
              AND key_ordinal > 0
              ORDER BY index_column_id

            SELECT @IncludedColumns = @IncludedColumns + ''['' + c.name + ''],'' from ['+@SourceDatabase+'].sys.index_columns ic
              INNER JOIN ['+@SourceDatabase+'].sys.columns c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
              WHERE index_id = @IndexId 
              AND ic.object_id = object_id(''['+@SourceDatabase+'].[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']'') 
              AND key_ordinal = 0
              ORDER BY index_column_id

            IF LEN(@KeyColumns) > 0
                SET @KeyColumns = LEFT(@KeyColumns, LEN(@KeyColumns) - 1)

            IF LEN(@IncludedColumns) > 0
            BEGIN
                SET @IncludedColumns = '' INCLUDE ('' + LEFT(@IncludedColumns, LEN(@IncludedColumns) - 1) + '')''
            END

            IF @FilterDefinition IS NULL
                SET @FilterDefinition = ''''
            ELSE
                SET @FilterDefinition = ''WHERE '' + @FilterDefinition + '' ''

            if @IsUniqueConstraint = 0
                exec(''CREATE '' + @Unique + '' NONCLUSTERED INDEX ['' + @IndexName + ''] ON [' + @DestinationDatabase + '].[' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] ('' + @KeyColumns + '')'' + @IncludedColumns + @FilterDefinition)
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @IndexName = REPLACE(@IndexName, ''' + @SourceTable + ''', ''' + @DestinationTable + ''')
                    exec(''ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationDatabase + '].[' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] ADD  CONSTRAINT ['' + @IndexName + ''] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ('' + @KeyColumns + '')'')
                END

            FETCH NEXT FROM indexcursor INTO @IndexId, @IndexName, @IsUnique, @IsUniqueConstraint, @FilterDefinition;
       END;
    CLOSE indexcursor;
    DEALLOCATE indexcursor;

    --create constraints
    DECLARE @ConstraintName nvarchar(max), @CheckClause nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE constraintcursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT REPLACE(c.CONSTRAINT_NAME, ''' + @SourceTable + ''', ''' + @DestinationTable + '''), CHECK_CLAUSE 
          FROM [' + @SourceDatabase + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE t
          INNER JOIN [' + @SourceDatabase + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS c ON c.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = TABLE_SCHEMA AND c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
          WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + @SourceSchema + ''' 
          AND TABLE_NAME = ''' + @SourceTable + '''
    OPEN constraintcursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM constraintcursor INTO @ConstraintName, @CheckClause;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN
            exec(''ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationDatabase + '].[' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT ['' + @ConstraintName + ''] CHECK '' + @CheckClause)
            exec(''ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationDatabase + '].[' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] CHECK CONSTRAINT ['' + @ConstraintName + '']'')
            FETCH NEXT FROM constraintcursor INTO @ConstraintName, @CheckClause;
       END;
    CLOSE constraintcursor;
    DEALLOCATE constraintcursor;'

    --PRINT SUBSTRING(@sql, 0, 4000)
    --PRINT SUBSTRING(@sql, 4000, 8000)

    EXEC(@sql)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quick and dirty mod, based on this question:  [Generate CREATE scripts for a list of indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121522/generate-create-scripts-for-a-list-of-indexes) but should get you most of the way there. You could do what you are already doing to clone the structure, and you a version of this proc to do they indexes and then modify as necessary:

```
   CREATE sp_CloneIndex   @OldTableName varchar(50), @NewTableName varchar(50)
  AS

WITH indexCTE AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
    i.index_id, i.name, i.object_id
FROM 
    sys.indexes i 
INNER JOIN
    sys.index_columns ic 
       ON i.index_id = ic.index_id AND i.object_id = ic.object_id
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns c WHERE c.column_id = ic.column_id AND c.object_id = ic.object_id)
), 
indexCTE2 AS
(
SELECT 
    indexCTE.name 'IndexName', 
    OBJECT_NAME(indexCTE.object_ID) 'TableName',
    CASE indexCTE.index_id 
      WHEN 1 THEN 'CLUSTERED'
      ELSE 'NONCLUSTERED'
    END AS 'IndexType', 
    (SELECT DISTINCT c.name + ','
     FROM 
        sys.columns c 
     INNER JOIN
        sys.index_columns ic 
           ON c.object_id = ic.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id AND ic.Is_Included_Column = 0
     WHERE
        indexCTE.OBJECT_ID = ic.object_id 
        AND indexCTE.index_id = ic.index_id 
     FOR XML PATH('')
    ) ixcols,
    ISNULL(
    (SELECT DISTINCT c.name + ','
     FROM 
        sys.columns c 
     INNER JOIN
        sys.index_columns ic 
           ON c.object_id = ic.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id AND ic.Is_Included_Column = 1
     WHERE
        indexCTE.OBJECT_ID = ic.object_id 
        AND indexCTE.index_id = ic.index_id 
     FOR XML PATH('')
    ), '') includedcols
FROM 
    indexCTE
) 
SELECT 
'CREATE ' + IndexType + ' INDEX ' + IndexName + ' ON ' + @NewTableName + 
    '(' + SUBSTRING(ixcols, 1, LEN(ixcols)-1) + 
    CASE LEN(includedcols)
      WHEN 0 THEN ')'
      ELSE ') INCLUDE (' + SUBSTRING(includedcols, 1, LEN(includedcols)-1) + ')'
    END
FROM 
 indexCTE2
where tablename = @OldTableName
ORDER BY 
  TableName, IndexName
```

Comment: As @JNKs answer mentions, there are lots of other details to get right if you want 100% perfect cloning (e.g. the above doesn't even deal with `ASC` or `DESC`), and doesn't even necessarily get the columns in the right order.

Comment: Yes, and I had no intention of writing the whole script for the OP, just pushing the ball a bit further down the road

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version. The destination table and schema are the same like the source with something added at the end in my case _STG. You can add something at the end using @NameAdd NVARCHAR(128) variable. I did it this way to avoid sql injection. In my version no outside provided text is executed.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name='uspCloneTableStructure')
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspCloneTableStructure]
END
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspCloneTableStructure]
    @inSourceSchema nvarchar(128),
    @inSourceTable nvarchar(128),
    @RecreateTable bit = 0,
    @RecreateIndexes bit = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @RecID INT
       ,@RecCount INT
       ,@ExecuteCMD NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
       ,@DateTime VARCHAR(100)
       ,@SourceSchema NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@SourceTable NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@DestinationSchema NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@DestinationTable NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@NameAdd NVARCHAR(128) = N'_STG';

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN TRY;
        SET XACT_ABORT ON;
        SELECT  @SourceSchema = s.name
               ,@SourceTable = t.name
               ,@DestinationSchema = s.name
               ,@DestinationTable = t.name + @NameAdd
        FROM    sys.tables AS t
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
        ON      s.schema_id = t.schema_id
        WHERE   s.name = @inSourceSchema
                AND t.name = @inSourceTable;

        --drop the table
        if @RecreateTable = 1 AND @DestinationSchema IS NOT NULL AND @DestinationTable IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @ExecuteCMD ='IF EXISTS (SELECT *   FROM sys.tables AS t 
                                        INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
                                            ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                                        WHERE s.name = ''' + @DestinationSchema + ''' AND t.name = ''' + @DestinationTable + ''')
                                            DROP TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + ']

                              SELECT TOP (0) * INTO [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] FROM [' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']';
            SELECT @DateTime = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),GETDATE(),(121));
            RAISERROR('--Creating table: %s at: %s ',0,1,@DestinationTable,@DateTime) WITH NOWAIT;  
            PRINT @ExecuteCMD;
            EXECUTE sp_executesql @ExecuteCMD;
        END;

        IF @RecreateIndexes = 1
        BEGIN

            --create other indexes
            DECLARE @IndexId INT
               ,@IndexName NVARCHAR(128)
               ,@FilterDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX)
               ,@IsPrimaryKey BIT
               ,@Unique NVARCHAR(128)
               ,@Clustered NVARCHAR(128)
               ,@DataCompression NVARCHAR(60)
               ,@KeyColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)
               ,@IncludedColumns NVARCHAR(MAX);

            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Indexes') IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN 
                DROP TABLE dbo.#Indexes;
            END;

            CREATE TABLE dbo.#Indexes
                (
                 [RecID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
                ,IndexId INT
                ,IndexName NVARCHAR(128)
                ,IsUnique BIT
                ,FilterDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX)
                ,IsClustered INT
                ,IsPrimaryKey BIT
                ,DataCompression NVARCHAR(60)
                );

            INSERT INTO dbo.#Indexes
                    ( IndexId
                    ,IndexName
                    ,IsUnique
                    ,FilterDefinition
                    ,IsClustered
                    ,IsPrimaryKey
                    ,DataCompression )
            SELECT  i.index_id
                   ,i.name
                   ,i.is_unique
                   ,i.filter_definition
                   ,i.index_id
                   ,i.is_primary_key
                   ,sp.data_compression_desc
            FROM    sys.indexes AS i
            INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
            ON      t.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
            ON      s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
            INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS sp 
            ON      i.[object_id] = sp.[object_id]
                    AND i.[index_id] = sp.[index_id]
                    AND sp.partition_number = 1
            WHERE   i.type <>0 
                    AND s.name = @SourceSchema
                    AND t.name = @SourceTable;

            SELECT @RecCount = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.#Indexes;
            SET @RecID = 1;
            WHILE (@RecID <= @RecCount)     
            BEGIN
                SELECT  @IndexId = IndexId
                       ,@IndexName = IndexName
                       ,@Unique = CASE WHEN IsUnique = 1 THEN ' UNIQUE ' ELSE '' END
                       ,@FilterDefinition = FilterDefinition
                       ,@Clustered = CASE WHEN IsClustered = 1 THEN ' CLUSTERED ' ELSE ' NONCLUSTERED ' END
                       ,@IsPrimaryKey = IsPrimaryKey
                       ,@DataCompression = DataCompression
                       ,@KeyColumns = ''
                       ,@IncludedColumns = ''
                FROM    dbo.#Indexes
                WHERE   [RecID] = @RecID;

                SELECT  @KeyColumns = @KeyColumns + '[' + c.name + '] '
                        + CASE WHEN is_descending_key = 1 THEN 'DESC'
                               ELSE 'ASC'
                          END + ','
                FROM    sys.index_columns ic
                INNER JOIN sys.columns c
                ON c.object_id = ic.object_id
                    AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
                ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
                ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                WHERE   ic.index_id = @IndexId
                    AND s.name = @SourceSchema
                    AND t.name = @SourceTable
                    AND key_ordinal > 0
                ORDER BY index_column_id;

                SELECT  @IncludedColumns = @IncludedColumns + '[' + c.name + '],'
                FROM    sys.index_columns ic
                INNER JOIN sys.columns c
                ON      c.object_id = ic.object_id
                        AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
                ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
                ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                WHERE   ic.index_id = @IndexId
                    AND s.name = @SourceSchema
                    AND t.name = @SourceTable
                    AND key_ordinal = 0
                ORDER BY index_column_id;

                IF LEN(@KeyColumns) > 0
                    SET @KeyColumns = LEFT(@KeyColumns, LEN(@KeyColumns) - 1);

                IF LEN(@IncludedColumns) > 0
                BEGIN
                    SET @IncludedColumns = ' INCLUDE (' + LEFT(@IncludedColumns, LEN(@IncludedColumns) - 1) + ')';
                END

                IF @FilterDefinition IS NULL
                    SET @FilterDefinition = '';
                ELSE
                    SET @FilterDefinition = 'WHERE ' + @FilterDefinition + ' ';

                --create the index or PK
                IF @IsPrimaryKey = 1
                    SET @ExecuteCMD = 'ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] ADD  CONSTRAINT [' + @IndexName + @NameAdd + '] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (' + @KeyColumns + ') WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB=ON,DATA_COMPRESSION='+@DataCompression+');';
                ELSE
                    SET @ExecuteCMD = 'CREATE ' + @Unique + @Clustered + ' INDEX [' + @IndexName + '] ON [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] (' + @KeyColumns + ')' + @IncludedColumns + @FilterDefinition + ' WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB=ON,DATA_COMPRESSION='+@DataCompression+');';

                SELECT @DateTime = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),GETDATE(),(121));
                RAISERROR('--Creating index: %s%s at: %s ',0,1,@IndexName,@NameAdd,@DateTime) WITH NOWAIT;  
                PRINT @ExecuteCMD;
                EXECUTE sp_executesql @ExecuteCMD;

                SET @RecID = @RecID + 1;

            END;/*While loop*/
        END;

        COMMIT TRAN;
        SET XACT_ABORT OFF;
    END TRY BEGIN CATCH;
        SET XACT_ABORT OFF;
        IF (XACT_STATE() != 0)
        BEGIN;
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END;
        THROW;
        -- RETURN;
    END CATCH;
END

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Another procedure to clone ONLY foreign keys (Note that referenced table must already exists, obviously).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCloneFKStructure] 
    @SourceDatabase nvarchar(max),
    @SourceSchema nvarchar(max),
    @SourceTable nvarchar(max),
    @DestinationDatabase nvarchar(max),
    @DestinationSchema nvarchar(max),
    @DestinationTable nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    set @sql = '

    --create foreign keys
    DECLARE @ConstraintName nvarchar(max),@ColName nvarchar(max),@RefTable nvarchar(max),@RefColName nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE fkcursor CURSOR FOR
    select a.name,c.name,object_name(b.referenced_object_id,db_id(''' + @SourceDatabase + ''')),d.name 
    from [' + @SourceDatabase + '].sys.foreign_keys a
        join [' + @SourceDatabase + '].sys.foreign_key_columns b on a.object_id=b.constraint_object_id
        join [' + @SourceDatabase + '].sys.columns c on b.parent_column_id = c.column_id and a.parent_object_id=c.object_id
        join [' + @SourceDatabase + '].sys.columns d on b.referenced_column_id = d.column_id and a.referenced_object_id = d.object_id
    where   
        object_name(a.parent_object_id,db_id(''' + @SourceDatabase + ''')) = ''' + @SourceTable + ''' order by c.name
    OPEN fkcursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM fkcursor INTO @ConstraintName, @ColName, @RefTable, @RefColName;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN
            exec(''ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationDatabase + '].[' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] ADD CONSTRAINT ['' + @ConstraintName + ''] FOREIGN KEY ('' + @ColName + '') REFERENCES '' + @RefTable + ''('' + @RefColName + '')'')
            FETCH NEXT FROM fkcursor INTO @ConstraintName, @ColName, @RefTable, @RefColName;
       END;
    CLOSE fkcursor;
    DEALLOCATE fkcursor;'

    exec(@sql)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```