# Trying to copy complete table(s) during signup into another schema

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a multitenant application What I had planned to transfer tables from default schema i.e. dbo to another schema, I am using a stored Proc to create new schema with all relations being maintained within dbo

```
USE [STAGING]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Dheeraj Singh
-- Create date: getdate
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[-old-sp_transfer_schema_on_signup]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@NewSchema varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @id INT
    DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @getid CURSOR

    BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION SCHEDULEDELETE
  SET @getid = CURSOR FOR select name from sys.Objects where sys.Objects.schema_id=1 and type in     ('U','V')
    OPEN  @getid
    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT
        FROM @getid INTO @name
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS < 0 BREAK
        
        exec( 'SELECT * INTO [' + @NewSchema + '].[' + @name + '] FROM dbo.[' + @name+ ']')
        --EXEC stored_proc @varName=@id, @otherVarName='test', @varForName=@name
    END
    CLOSE @getid
    DEALLOCATE @getid
     COMMIT TRANSACTION SCHEDULEDELETE
    PRINT 'X rows deleted. Operation Successful Tara.' --calculation cut out.
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH 
      IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
       BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION SCHEDULEDELETE
      PRINT 'Error detected, all changes reversed'
   END 
    SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
    ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
    ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
    ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
    ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
    ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
END CATCH

    
END
```

What I was expecting is to copy all the tables from dbo to the newly created schema, but it was not able to copy relations and keys during this transfer

Comment: Deploy from your Source Control and your database project for the new schema, that'll Deploy objects in the correct order. Also, 2008 has been end of life for well over a year, you should long be looking at upgrade paths.

Comment: Because that is what <select ... into ...> does. This logic is seriously flawed for many reasons. Permissions? Indexes? FG allocation? You assume far too much. You eat any error and return it as a regular resultset - it only "looks" like an error to a person. And not adhering to the regular identifier rules is a bad sign generally.

Comment: This resolved my problem I missed it:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582852/programmatically-copy-indexes-from-one-table-to-another-in-sql-server